# show and hide password in Tkinter with binding Button and ButtonRelease?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-button

I'm learning Python3 and tkinter. I was trying to show password with binding `<Button>` and hide password with binding `<ButtonRelease>`, but I didn't have any solution. All I can do is to show the password, then the error occurred:

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

def show(e):
    passwd_entry.config(show="")
# def hide(event):
#     passwd_entry.config(show="*")
root = tk.Tk()

passwd_entry = tk.Entry(root, show='*', width=20)
passwd_entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

toggle_btn = tk.Button(root, text='Show Password', width=15, command=show)
toggle_btn.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
toggle_btn.bind("<Button>", show)
# toggle_btn.bind("<ButtonRelease>", hide)

root.mainloop()
```

This is the error when I click `button`:

```
TypeError: show() missing 1 required positional argument: 'e'
```

Comment: Why is `e` passed as an argument to `show()`?

Comment: Oh. I need to remove the event . Thanks. But I’m still in trouble the problem mentioned above.

Comment: Add your modified approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tkinter` instance creation needs to happen before the function definition event which you want to call.

Also use the lambda function to call the show function inside `bind` as mentioned in below code. It should help.

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def show():
    passwd_entry.config(show="")
def hide():
    passwd_entry.config(show="*")

passwd_entry = tk.Entry(root, show='*', width=20)
passwd_entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

toggle_btn = tk.Button(root, text='Show Password', width=15)
toggle_btn.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
toggle_btn.bind("<ButtonPress>", lambda event:show())
toggle_btn.bind("<ButtonRelease>", lambda event:hide())

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, but this makes the password visible and cannot make invisible anymore. I'm trying to make the password visible when left-click and make it invisible when releasing left-click.

Comment: Updated the code, please check, now you can show or hide the password with any click be it right click or left click :) Please accept the answer and upvote if it helps :)